# How to cut piece of fabric in a way that won't unravel the rest of the fabric?

Tags: fabric

I have a piece of fabric that I want to remove:

[image: fabric with extra piece that should be removed]

The cloth arrived this way from the factory, looks like a production bug. I didn't try to stitch or anything else with the fabric yet, except initial washing.

From experience, if I'll just cut it with scissors it will cause the rest of the fabric to start unravel at the point of the cutting.

Any way to remove the extra piece without risk of damaging the rest? I prefer something other than sewing techniques, since I'm pretty sure I'll fail in those.

Comment: *Why* is there a loose end of fabric? Did come unstitched? Were you sewing the item yourself and don't know how to finish it off (tuck the end under like a hem and sew it the the main part). If it's a man-made fibre it can be prevented from fraying with heat (warning: don't try this as home if you had to ask). Or with a small piece of iron-on tape folded round it. And so on, I can't see why this a **hack** and not normal sewing techniques.

Comment: @WeatherVane thanks, added the details to the question.

Answer (score 3):

The tiny piece you're holding in the picture is not a piece of fabric, it's (for lack of a better word) a "braid" of threads that extends from the seam. This is a very common thing in cheap fast-fashion garments because the underpaid workers don't care (and aren't paid) to finish their seams properly.

If you cut it too close to the actual garment, the individual threads will unravel and undo the seam.

**Hack 1**: The neat solution

Fold the protruding seam back onto the garment. Thread a piece of while thread through a hand sewing needle and start sewing over the existing seam in a zigzag. Start at the very edge of the garment and sew to a centimeter or 1/2 inch after the end of the protrusion. That new seam holds all the threads of the old seam in place and keeps it neat.

**Hack 2**: The lazy solution

Fold the protruding seam back onto the garment and glue it in place with fabric glue. If you don't have fabric glue, transparent waterproof glues like transparent acryllic may work as well. If all things fail, a tiny dab of transparent construction silicone sure does the job.

Be aware that all of the mentioned glues can leave ugly stains behind and stay visible after they dried. Many of them will not withstand washing very well (even most fabric glues slowly dissolve during laundry).

Comment: Thanks, I was lacking proper words as well, hence couldn't describe the situation very well. Will give the lazy solution a try. :)

Answer (score 1):

The two methods by Elmy work.
As someone who has sewn all her life, I would use a third method. I would undo that sticking out 'braid' and stop its unraveling just before it reaches the fabric and use its own thread to fix it from unraveling further and coming undone. Mostly you only have to catch one loop of the 'braid', sew through that and the fabric, and give it a few stitches to fix it. Then you also sew the other ends a few stitches to fix them.

Or I would identify the loop nearest the fabric and cut through it, so the braid does fix itself. (But doing this wrong does allow it to run out so keep glue handy if you do not sew.)